# Why is BufferedReader::readLine hanging at EOF?

Tags: java, file-io

I have some Java 8 code that's attempting to read the contents of a file (including newlines) into one String; here are the guts:

```
static private void fn( BufferedReader reader ) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( 1000000 );
    String line = null;
    while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
        builder.append( line ).append( '\n' );
        System.err.println( line );
    }
    String text = builder.toString();
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    fn( reader );
}
```

I'm running this under a Run Configuration in Eclipse that redirects `System.in` from a file (which does end with an EOF), and the print statements confirm that the lines are, indeed, getting read, but once the read goes past the last line, it hangs in the Eclipse debugger.

I haven't had this problem with reading from other files in this way; why now?

Comment: For what it’s worth, if you’re using Java 11 or later, you can use the [Files.readString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method instead.

Comment: Unlike reading from a file, System.in is still open to receiving more bytes to send to your reader. You can overcome this using a callback pattern like in DataFetcher: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java

Comment: @ControlAltDel Since `System.in` is redirected to read from a file, shouldn't the end of stream be reached? Or does this setup allow one to write more to the file which will be seen and read by the system input?

Comment: @Slaw I think the situation is not that System.in is redirected to read from the file, but rather that the file's contents are piped into System.in

Comment: I solved my problem by opening the BufferedReader explicitly on the file itself, rather than redirecting to ```System.in```   Still don't understand what was happening, but understanding may be overrated.

Comment: Which JDK version was used? I find it's OK with java version "1.8.0_131" and IntelliJ idea 2018.3.5